# In django-allauth: integrations with Kakao, I entered all the keys as in Documentations

Tags: django, django-allauth

KeyError at /accounts/kakao/login/callback/
'kakao account'
**

```
def extract_common_fields(self, data):
        email = data["kakao_account"].get("email")
```

**
kakao account is not present, anyone can help,
thanks in advance